# Best Schema for a Data List in JSON for RestFul API to use in Angular

Tags: json, angular

I've been wondering for some days what kind of scheme would be more appropriate to use a data list in json in a web application.
I'm developing a REST Web Application, and im using Angular for front end, i should order, filter and print these data list also in xml ...
For you what scheme is better and why?

```
1) {
  "datas": [
    { "first":"","second":""},
    { "first":"","second":""},
    { "first":"","second":""}
]
}


2) {
    "datas": [{
    "data": { "first":"","second":""},
    "data": { "first":"","second":""},
    "data": { "first":"","second":""}
}]
}

3) [
        { "first":"","second":""},
        { "first":"","second":""},
        { "first":"","second":""}
    ]
```

Thanks so much.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The first and third notations are quite similar because the third notation is included in your first.
So the question is "Should I return my datas as an array or should I return an object with a property that contain the array ?

It will depend on either you want to have more information alongside your datas or not.
For exemple, if your API might return an error, you will want to manage it from the front end.
In case of error, the JSON will looks like this :

```
{
  "datas": null,
  "error": "An error occured because of some reasons..."
}
```

At the opposite, if everything goes well and your API actually return the results, it will looks like this :

```
{
  "datas": [
    { "first":"","second":""},
    { "first":"","second":""},
    { "first":"","second":""}
  ],
  "error": null
}
```

Then your front end can use the error property to manage errors sent from the API.

```js
var result = getDatas(); // Load datas from the API

if(result.error){
  // Handle the error, display a message to the user, ...
} else {
  doSomething(result.datas); // Use your datas
}
```

If you don't need to have extra properties like `error` then you can stick with the third schema.

---

The second notation is invalid. The `datas` array will contain only one object which will have one property named `data`. In this case `data` is a property that is defined multiple times so the object in the array will contain only the last occurence:

```js
var result = {
  "datas": [{
    "data": { "first":"a","second":"b"},
    "data": { "first":"c","second":"d"},
    "data": { "first":"e","second":"f"}
  }]
}

console.log("Content of result.datas[0].data : ")
console.log(result.datas[0].data)
```

Comment: Thank you for your explanation. I'm agree with you.

Answer (score 0):

Obviously the first option would be easy to use. Once you will access `datas` it'll give you an array. Any operation (filter, sort, print) on that array will be easy in comparison to anything else. Everywhere you just need to pass `datas` not `datas.data`.

Comment: Thanks for your opinion , but is not the same case of the third option?

Comment: Where is the object to access the array in 3rd option?

Comment: You can iterate giving a alias in code of Front End.